# Cannot subscribe to topics using rosbag play

Tags: rosbag, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to subscribe to a message which is being played back from a bag file.  Whenever I launch my node that listens to the topic, I get the following error:

Dec 11, 2012 6:27:57 AM org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler exceptionCaught
SEVERE: Channel exception: java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out

The rxgraph output shows my node, but it is in red.  It shows the bagplay node and rosout normally.  Can ROSJava not connect to the topics published from a bag file?  What am I doing wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50164/cannot-subscribe-to-topics-using-rosbag-play/) by [amittleider](https://answers.ros.org/users/2448/amittleider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 227 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a problem with ROS_IP, ROS_MASTER_URI, or your NodeConfiguration. See:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables
http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#executing-nodes

If this doesn't address your issue, please edit your post to explain how you configure and launch the node.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0